# Alternative ways to cast an interface to its implementation

Tags: java, types, interface, casting

Suppose I have an interface and implementation:

```
public interface ITest {
}

public TestClass implements ITest {
}
```

In my code, I have some method:

```
public void pass(ITest testObject) {
    //
}
```

Without knowing in advance what implementation of `ITest` I'm dealing with in the above method, how do I cast to `TestClass`? For example, in the above method I could do the cast `((TestClass)testObject)` but this requires prior knowledge of the implementation, which I want you to assume that I don't have. (I understand I can check all `instanceof` and cast to the correct implementation, but I don't want to do this).

I'm hoping for something like `testObject.getImplementation()` which returns a `TestClass` instance if and only if `testObject` is an `instanceof` the class `TestClass` (and likewise of any other implementations if `ITest`).

Comment: Why would you *want* to cast to `TestClass`? If you don't know about the class in advance in your method, what are you trying to do with it? I suspect that if you take your thinking further in terms of what you're trying to do, you'll discover other problems.

Comment: If you want to cast, then why do you use interface at all?

Answer (score 0):

You could use Object's [`getClass`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Object.html#getClass()) method and you'll get the implementing class.

Answer (score 0):

Something is wrong in your design. If you need to make a cast, it seems that your interface is too generic.

The best way is to add a new method in interface: e.g. **isOK().** Every implementation will selfcheck in **isOK()** method.

The code will become

```
public void pass(ITest testObject) {
    if (testObject.isOk()) {...}
}
```

So the need for cast is not required anymore.

Answer (score 0):

You could use the [Visitor pattern](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Visitor_pattern), but I rather suspect that you would be better off looking into your design. Maybe `ITest` should be exposing a method?